# SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync throws UnauthorizedAccessException in PeriodicScheduledTask of my agent project

Tags: windows-phone-8

Just as titled, I get the UnauthorizedAccessException error when try to call SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync from the OnInvoke method of my PeriodicScheduledTask.
In the main project, I already added the ID_CAP_SPEECH_RECOGNITION flag. Anything else I need to do?

Comment: Please delete your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137847/how-to-make-sound-using-background-agent) if you are replacing it with this one

Comment: Ok. Will do just that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call Speech Synthesis from a background agent, hence the exception. You can't just have your phone randomly start talking to you. You CAN create a toast notification that they click, which activates your app and navigates to a specific page... At that point you should be able to use speech just fine.

HTH!

Comment: Ok. But no documentation says that Speech api is unsupported in background agents. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: What namespace is the speech synthesizer in?